# How to autoscaling VM in Google Cloud Platform for WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

We are running a VM on GCP with 8GB ram and when traffic spike, the server crashed due to out of memory.  We are thinking autoscaling VM instead of adding more memory to the VM.

Then I found out we need to set up a load balancer and build instance group with instance template.

My question is does it works for Wordpress site which we keep adding the contents every day. How the autoscaling work for that situation?

Also, I found the monthly cost for setting up a load balancer is more than I add 2GB ram extra on the VM.

Any idea, how to handle the traffic spike on WordPress site?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you have MySQL installed (with WordPress or as Cloud SQL)? To autoscale WordPress will require MySQL running outside of your instance.

Comment: It is inside the VM and not the Cloud SQL, if move it out then the cost will even more with the load balancer and cloud SQL.

Comment: Correct. To enable autoscaling, you need to create your Wordpress instances to be static, which means any changes will be thrown away. This means Cloud SQL, Load Balancer and Instance Templates. This increases your baseline cost but gives you scalable and fault tolerant systems. I would also add Cloud Storage and Content Caching to to the mix.

Comment: Another method that I use on smaller Wordpress sites is to enable caching. For example on my personal blogging website I use `WP Fastest Cache`. This offloads a lot of traffic for my pages that don't change often to be pulled from memory cache. This can really decrease server load. You do need to select an instance large enought for Wordpress, MySQL and Caching. You do not mention your instance size, but anything smaller than `N1-Standard-1` is a toy (too small) for Wordpress. In some cases I can get away with `small` but the site goes down if there is any real traffic.

Answer (score 1):

To handle bursts of traffic for Wordpress you have several options:

1. Pick an instance size that can handle the traffic bursts. This may or may not be cost efficient. Just depends on how large of a difference you have between steady state traffic and peak traffic.
2. Implement content caching. Select a caching plugin to cache pages that do not change. This can decrease CPU and MySQL query traffic significantly. However, add more memory to your instance so that caching does take away memory for MySQL.
3. Implement load balancing, auto scaling, static Wordpress machine images and move MySQL to a separate instance or service. This is the best setup for Wordpress.

The key is to understand how Wordpress creates a web page. In most cases, Wordpress issues multiple queries to MySQL for content. This creates a lot of I/O. If your instance is small and short on memory, MySQL will not be able to cache your database content in memory. This means increased disk I/O. If during steady-state traffic your setup keeps data in MySQL cache memory and then during peaks MySQL is forced to go to disk, you site can become very slow or unresponsive. This is a metric that you want to figure out for your site.

Comment: Thanks for all replies, my instance is 2 vCPU  / 8GB ram and now increased to 12GB ram, it is $20 more but still cheaper than the autoscaling option. For caching plugin, there are so many of them some may not work well with other plugins, we using the X-theme with cornerstone as editor and with the translation WPML, Jetpack, Yoast SEO plugin, the traffic spike is not happening too often, once it hit the server, the OOM killer and start killing processes, I check the log it is too many HTTP requests, I don't know that related to the MySQL db or not, the db itself is very small only 50MB.